# Multiple select from CTE with different number of rows in a StoredProcedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression, multiple-select-query

How to do two select with joins from the cte's which returns total number of columns in the two selects?

I tried doing union but that appends to the same list and there is no way to differentiate for further use.

```
WITH campus AS
(SELECT DISTINCT CampusName, DistrictName
FROM            dbo.file
),creditAcceptance AS
(SELECT        CampusName, EligibilityStatusFinal, CollegeCreditAcceptedFinal, COUNT(id) AS N
FROM            dbo.file
WHERE        (EligibilityStatusFinal LIKE 'Eligible%') AND (CollegeCreditEarnedFinal = 'Yes') AND (CollegeCreditAcceptedFinal = 'Yes')
GROUP BY CampusName, EligibilityStatusFinal, CollegeCreditAcceptedFinal
),eligibility AS
(SELECT        CampusName, EligibilityStatusFinal, COUNT(id) AS N, CollegeCreditAcceptedFinal
FROM            dbo.file
WHERE        (EligibilityStatusFinal LIKE 'Eligible%') 
GROUP BY CampusName, EligibilityStatusFinal, CollegeCreditAcceptedFinal
)
SELECT        a.CampusName, c.[EligibilityStatusFinal], SUM(c.N) AS creditacceptCount
FROM            campus  as a FULL OUTER JOIN creditAcceptance as c ON a.CampusName=c.CampusName
WHERE        (a.DistrictName = 'xy')
group by a.CampusName ,c.EligibilityStatusFinal
Union ALL
SELECT      a.CampusName ,  b.[EligibilityStatusFinal], SUM(b.N) AS eligible
    From Campus as a FULL OUTER JOIN eligibility    as b ON a.CampusName = b.CampusName

WHERE        (a.DistrictName = 'xy') 
group by a.CampusName,b.EligibilityStatusFinal
```

Expected output:

```
+------------+------------------------+--------------------+
| CampusName | EligibilityStatusFinal | creditacceptCount  |
+------------+------------------------+--------------------+
| M          | G                      | 1                  |
| E          | NULL                   | NULL               |
| A          | G                      | 4                  |
| B          | G                      | 8                  |
+------------+------------------------+--------------------+

+------------+------------------------+----------+
| CampusName | EligibilityStatusFinal | eligible |
+------------+------------------------+----------+
| A          | G                      |        8 |
| C          | G                      |        9 |
| A          | T                      |        9 |
+------------+------------------------+----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) CTEs can be used in a single statement only, so you can't get the expected output with CTEs.

Here is an excerpt from Microsoft docs:

> A CTE must be followed by a **single** SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE
>   statement that references some or all the CTE columns. A CTE can also
>   be specified in a CREATE VIEW statement as part of the defining SELECT
>   statement of the view.

You can use table variables (`declare @campus table(...)`) or temp tables (`create table #campus (...)`) instead.